# SQL left join two times

Tags: mysql, sql

The user table looks like this:

| user_id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | aa |
| 2 | b | bb |
| 3 | c | cc |

The book's table looks like this:

| user_id | book_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 |
| 1 | book2 |
| 1 | book3 |
| 2 | book1 |

The expenses table looks like this:

| user_id | amount_spent | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-02-03 |
| 1 | 30 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-02-01 |
| 1 | 15 | 2020-01-31 |
| 1 | 13 | 2020-01-15 |
| 2 | 15 | 2020-02-01 |
| 3 | 20 | 2020-02-01 |

The result which I want:

| CountUsers | amount_spent |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 65 |

Explanation: I want to count how many users have book1 and how much total they spend on a date between 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03.

Now how the query should look like?

I am using MySQL version 8.

I have tried:

```sql
SELECT 
count(*), sum(amount_spend) as total_amount_spend
FROM
(select sum(amount_spend) as amount_spend
FROM expanses 
LEFT JOIN books ON books.user_id = expanses.user_id WHERE books.book_name ='book1 GROUP BY expanses.user_id) src'
```

And the result is wrong because I am getting a higher amount_spend than in my table result above. I think while joining the table there are some duplicates but I do not know how to fix them.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried so far and explain where/why it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: I do not know how to even start :( Could you help me?

Comment: Then you should first consult some SQL tutorial. Show some effort.

Comment: Ok, I have added what I tried.

Comment: @mickris your sql code will work (apart that you have `amount_spend` in code and `amount_spent` in tables) but what you're missing is date conditions. I believe that when you add such it will sum like in your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count how many users have book1 and how much total they spend on a date between 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03.

I am thinking:

```
select count(*), sum(e.amount_spent)
from user_books ub join
     expenses e
     on ub.user_id = e.user_id
where book_name = 'book1';
```

Note:  This assumes that `user_books` doesn't have duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDHKb6RrZcTjdpdXcFhPnV/1)

You miss the date part in your code.

```sql
SELECT
count(*), sum(amount_spent) as total_amount_spend
FROM
(select sum(amount_spent) as amount_spent
FROM expanses
LEFT JOIN books ON books.user_id = expanses.user_id
WHERE books.book_name ='book1' 
and expanses.date between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-03'
GROUP BY expanses.user_id) src;
```

will do a job.

---

Please note that you don't need to have `left join` here (unless you're sure that it may happen that no expenses at all for given user will be), and you don't need to have grouping in subquery. So your query could look like:

```sql
select count(distinct expanses.user_id), sum(amount_spent) as amount_spent
from expanses
inner join books on books.user_id = expanses.user_id
where books.book_name ='book1'
and expanses.date between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-03';
```

Comment: It does not work, because it is one to many relationship so the `sum(amount_spent)` will count amount_spent few times.

Comment: @mickris did you run that? There is a fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aDHKb6RrZcTjdpdXcFhPnV/1) which works exactly as intended - both your modified query and my proposition.

Comment: @mickris but if you have any other use case, or another data, or even different structure than you put into question, please prepare new fiddle (you can fork from this one or create new one).

Comment: Ah I did not see the fiddle, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042464/sql-left-join-with-sum-up) you have more explained my question

Comment: Please avoid creating new questions while you could adjust this one. By fiddle I meant example sql code with data and queries, not new question.

Comment: Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j4os5gCnWmd4WX21R6MKzw/0) which shows that your answer does not work :(

Comment: I'm confused now. I believe that my query works as intended, but as maybe we have different expectations about results, please add somewhere what exactly results you want to get. And you added `or` with another book into fiddle, this may change the results.